# Can I force compile-time failures in typescript if a boolean condition is not met, similar to compilation errors in C

Tags: typescript

Does Typescript have similar functionality to a compile-time check of a value that fails the build? How can I force my Typescript to fail if a condition is not met in code, as in this example?

```
if (compilestep.value !== 'compile step should have this value')
  // fail to compile, exit with an error code and pretty messaging
```

No, I don't want to wait for tests to run before checking this value. It must fail to compile, because that saves me about 9,000 hours waiting for builds to be tested.

There are similar language features in the C programming language. If a value that must be computed by the compiler is checked against a known condition, a failure to meet the condition will throw an error during compile-time for the developer to notice RIGHT AWAY!

Can I make the compiler blow up on this line:

```js
   if (todays.date.year !== '2023')
     BLOW UP AT COMPILE TIME NOT RUNTIME
```

Comment: I'm going to disengage here, I'm not really interested in pushback or arguing further in favor of a [mre]. If you don't think you need to present a [mre] then hopefully someone else will be able to help. Good luck!

Comment: as i have provided on the last line, i just want to check a boolean condition, say, today's date, against a known value of the date the last time the code compiled. if the dates don't match, then i have to update the code before compiling will succeed. there is no "reproducible" example, because it's a language feature i'm looking for, and if i knew how to reproduce it i wouldn't need to ask this question. thanks for your input!

Comment: @jcalz my sincere apologies (sometimes i forget people exist on the other end), your insistence on reproducing the example helped me understand that i had incorrectly identified the only answer as the correct one. your comments that you removed were valuable, and i thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Typescript have similar functionality to a compile-time check of a value that fails the build?

Actually, TS does thanks [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.learningtypescript.com/articles/the-satisfies-operator).

Here is an example with strings: notice that here it is essential that `exp` has a constant string type, if `exp` had the type `string`, then any string would satisfy its type:

```
const exp = "EXP";

declare const act: string;

if (act === exp) {
  act satisfies typeof exp;
}

if (act !== exp) {
  act satisfies typeof exp;
  // ERROR: 'string' does not satisfy '"EXP"'
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwA4wLwwEQFEAaAFDAbgChiATOYAGwEMAnOGUSWG4KALhmjoEswA5iWK8AZjAAUbWKlnxkAShgBvYjBjTuNKLwijecCDCgBPJHBDjESEgF9SYyZoCEc60tXrNEbbv2HjMwsrZBJ1AHpwmCwAJRiAeRiuAHIefgFkmDIQALAQWB8dPRMYZOx8DGTieyA)

Comment: Why should the compiler need to know the literal type of "act"?  The comparison is doing the guarding...  I have also tried with `act: unknown`, `act: any`, `act: number`, etc. and it works fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am not even sure the OP is comparing strings: I am simply answering the question as given, as it does make sense to me, title to begin with, and the answer I think simply is "the satisfies operator".

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio pretty sure this blows up at runtime, not compile time. i'm curious if typescript has this feature, because i know javascript doesn't (javascript doesn't compile; it's interpreted)

Comment: @activedecay No, `satisfies` does a check at *compile*-time, i.e. the code won't compile.  Try the code in the TS playground, I have added the link in my answer.

Comment: unfortunately, i chased jcalz off, sorry! i can be a pain sometimes. anyway, jcalz is correct and had a great comment that went something like: "your solution doesn't check a value that is unknown to the compiler. we don't know the value ahead of time (during writing the code)." so, not going to cut the mustard.